# Apache mod_wsgi Django setup - Forbidden You don't have permission to access /mysite on this server

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have install python 26, Apache 2.2, modwsgi ap2.2 py26 On windows XP.
and apache loads modwsgi fine.
when I check localhost: apache says - It works!
but when i try to open the Django directory mysite: localhost/mysite i
get :
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /mysite on this server.
I have re-installed and installed this many times but still the same
thing. The tutorial says should get: It worked
httpd.conf
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIScriptAlias / /mysite/apache/mysite.wsgi
runs fine, as in: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/
My project path is C:\mysite
and according to "http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/"
mysite.wsgi path is C:\mysite\apache\mysite.wsgi
I have search the for this problem but solution on the Linux please any one give me the answer for windows.

and error log is:-
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/mysite/apache/mysite.wsgi
could someone please help with this...
thanks

Comment: I think you might have more luck at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Here is a more detailed description of the configuration. http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango Follow the steps carefully and post the stack trace of the errors that you are getting for better understanding of the issue.

Comment: You really need to post the relevant section of the Apache configuration files to get good answers.

Answer (score 2):

This configuration snippet is from Linux, not Windows, but (pathname differences aside) should be pretty representative of a good mod_wsgi configuration.  Given the symptoms you've described, it sounds like you didn't get the directory permissions block for `mysite.wsgi` correct.  In short, anyone you want to view any part of your site must have 'access' to the directory that contains that file.

```
WSGIProcessGroup  foo
WSGIDaemonProcess foo processes=2 threads=5 home=/data/web/foo display-name=foo

DocumentRoot /var/www

WSGIScriptAlias / /data/web/foo/apache/django.wsgi
<Directory /data/web/foo/apache>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /data/web/foo/site/foo/static/
<Directory /data/web/foo/site/foo/static/>
  SetHandler None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I always get the same error no matter what I try, 403 Forbidden. Using Apache 2.2. I went through 5 different tutorials. I wish there was one that showed all httpd.conf contents and the wsgi file as well as all step by step. I will stick to nginx in the interest of saving time

Answer (score 0):

add following code in httpd.conf:

```
<Directory C:/mysite/apache>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```